# How to catch non-block subthread's exception and break the main thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am weak in the multi-threading area in python.
Now i have a request, here are the pseudo code:

```
def main():
    try:
        print("A")
        start_non_block_thread(func=test_func)
        time.sleep(10)
        print("B")
     except Exception:
        print("catch it")
def test_func():
    print("in sub-threading")
    raise Exception("quit")
```

The output i want is:

```
A
in sub-threading
catch it
```

Pls note that there is not "B" in the output.

How can i implement the start_non_block_thread to make sure the behavior is as my expected?

Thanks in advance~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exception capture in threads and parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433818/exception-capture-in-threads-and-parent)

Comment: No, this is different.  Because in my question, i want to break what the main thread is doing and start to handle the exception captured in the sub threading.

Comment: why do you expect `"A"` to be printed but not `"B"`? thread execution is not like serial execution, the thread might "except" before `"A"` is printed, or after `"B"` - you cannot have this type of control over the schedule of the thread/main execution.

Comment: Emm, i assume that the exception in the sub-thread occurs between "A" and "B".  Maybe the pseudo code is a bit bad-logic. But the purpose i want is that when the main thread prints "A", the sub thread raises an exception, then the main thread skip to print B and instead, hit the exception block.

Comment: then why threads? you describe a sequential code... this is not the way threads behave.